# Writing Assembly on Perl

Tags: perl, ffi

I want to write a small assembly code and call it from Perl :

I look at cpan and find those 2  Perl modules

1. https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::ASM which is very old
2. https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus::Lang::ASM which mention that it possible to call assembly from perl , i look at the examples but didn't find any example related to assembly code.

any idea how to use FFI::Platypus::Lang::ASM with Perl , an example will be appreciated

Comment: As for the age of Inline::ASM... Why does that matter?

Comment: It is also very simple to call assembly from Perl6 if you compile to a shared object and use the `NativeCall` interface, see [this talk](https://archive.fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/assembly_and_perl/) at FOSDEM 2016.

Comment: There's also the question of why you think you need to write code in asm.  It's very hard for humans to write efficient asm code these days (due to the increasing complexity of CPU's out of order execution).  Writing it in C with a decent optimizing compiler might be a better solution.  It's likely to be more portable and more maintainable as well.

Comment: @ikegami nothing matter , i mean it seems not maintained 18 years , at any case i am going to give it a try

Comment: @DavidWohlferd sometimes there are an extreme cases , where you want to check some , for example i want to write a subrotine on perl which return the CPUID Manifcator Id , do you know if there a perl wrapper about such feature , or how to achive this using some perl module ?

Comment: A google search for `perl manufacturer id` turns up a few hits.  Failing that, duskwuff mentions a tool for accessing C code.

Answer (score 5):

> any idea how to use FFI::Platypus::Lang::ASM with Perl , an example will be appreciated

The author of that module hasn't provided any examples for that code themselves. It looks like it may be an unfinished project.

Anyways, this is a pretty odd thing to want to do. Perl operates a couple levels of abstraction away from assembly -- interoperation between them is awkward at best.

A more practical solution will be to write C code which calls into your assembly code (or embeds it as inline assembly), then adapt that code to Perl using XS.